# Calculus 2 Triple Integral For Volume Below Function $z=e^{y^2}$.

Tags: calculus, volume

I am trying to solve the problem:

Find the volume below the graph of the function $z=e^{y^2}$ and above $z=0$, while $D:\{(x,y) \ | \ 0\le x \le 1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ x\le y\le 1\}$.

Trying to use triple integral $\mathrm dz \mathrm dy \mathrm dx$, limits for $z$ are $0$ to $e^{y^2}$ and for $y$ limits are $x$ to $1$ and for $x$ is $0$ to $1$.

I am not getting the right answer, it should be $0.5e-0.5$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange the order of integration: from $0 \le x \le 1$ and $x \le y \le 1$, we obtain $0 \le y \le 1$ and $0 \le x \le y$. So:
$$\iint_D e^{y^2}\text{d}x\text{d}y=\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^y e^{y^2}\text{d}x\right)\text{d}y=\int_0^1 ye^{y^2}\text{d}y=\left[\frac{1}{2}e^{y^2}\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{2}(e-1)$$

Comment: Thanks alot, but when and why should i obtain the limits for x before y like why do i need to bound x with y and not the opposite ? how i conclude that i should do dzdxdy and dzdydx ?

Comment: @Ipixiel You're welcome. Unfortunately, there is no general rule. Of course, here you can see that if you integrate first with respect to $y$ you get stuck because $e^{y^2}$ is not elementary integrable (that is, there is no antiderivative of the function $e^{y^2}$ that can be expressed using elementary functions). However, if you integrate before with respect to $x$ as I did, it will appear an $y$ that multiplies $e^{y^2}$ so that the integration is possible. With practice, you'll gain confidence in this kind of reasonings. If I helped, you can upvote my answer and select the ✔ button.